# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'xlsx'

Tags: javascript, json, excel, require, browserify

I am trying to see a log of the excel tab called UK in my excel sheet called Artists however it doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried to follow youtube videos and online, but I'm stuck as none of them worked.

**JAVASCRIPT FILE**

```
const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const workbook = XLSX.readFile("Artists.xlsx");
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets("UK");
const UK = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

console.log(UK);
```

**HTML FILE**

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link id="style" rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/main.css">
    <title>Drag Simulator</title>
    <script type="module" src="./JS/bundle.js"></script>
    <script lang="javascript" src="./node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've downloaded Node.JS, I've downloaded Browserify & xlsx in the terminal however I'm getting the below error

***"cannot find module (xlsx)"***

Comment: Have you installed a module called "xlsx"? Show package.json and Browserify setup.

Comment: Sorry, where would I find that, do I need to download that too?

Comment: I've got Package json, Browerify and XLSX module, but it still says I don't @guy

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have Node.js installed on your system.

Then, navigate to the directory where your project is and open a terminal.

In the terminal, run `npm install xlsx`.

This will import the 'xlsx' module and allow you to use its functions in your code.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this now and reply back afterwards.

Comment: I've updated the post, I installed node & xlsx however it's still got the same error.

Comment: If possible, could you upload a picture of your file structure?

Comment: I've updated it above to show file structure.

Comment: Is that the full file structure? Usually if you run `npm install`, it will generate a folder called node_modules in your file structure. Also, I forgot to mention one step: try running `npm init` from your terminal, click "Enter" for all the options, and then try running `npm install xlsx` again.

Comment: I've followed this and it's now made the node folder, however it's still not functioning.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's a little difficult for me to help with this if I can't interact with your code directly. Is there any way you could make the code public somewhere? You could use something like  https://codesandbox.io